# Android Java : "ClickerActivity" (View) in MainActivity cannot be applied

Tags: java, android

I'm newbie in progamming and I got simple code, but it won't work for me.

I got simple menu with lists, and functions with intents to go on other activities.

**Code :**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_click:
                ClickerActivity();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_upgrades:
                UpgradesActivity();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_warehouse:
                WarehouseActivity();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_postservice:
                PostServiceActivity();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_shop:
                ShopActivity();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_market:
                //MarketActivity();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_garage:
                GarageActivity();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void ClickerActivity(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void UpgradesActivity(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UpgradesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `ClickerActivity` function expecting a `View` input which is not required in this case so remove it

If you are using `ClickerActivity` in your `XML` with `OnClick` the better option is just copy your `intent` code inside switch case

Use this

```
public void ClickerActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

instead of this

```
public void ClickerActivity(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. :) I will check your answer correct after 10minutes. Where can I read about View view, etc? I just tought it need to be in every function.

Comment: @Crelix your welcome , basically View is a parent of all widgets (button,spinner etc) the way you are using is only required when you need to set `ClickListner` from `any_activity.xml` or when you want to do something with that widget in some function, for reading `android.developer` official site is best , try the `training` section there plus there are many other sites too which offer different-2 way to explain things

Answer (score 0):

you can also find your way like this..

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_click:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_upgrades:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UpgradesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_warehouse:
            WarehouseActivity();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_postservice:
            PostServiceActivity();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_shop:
            ShopActivity();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_market:
            //MarketActivity();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_garage:
            GarageActivity();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will help me too. :)